# ASP.Net Custom Validator control with DropDownList

Tags: asp.net

The following code is used for validating DropDownList control using Custom Validator.

Default1.aspx

```
<td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Product" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="128px">
             <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Nokia</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>LG</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Samsung</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>sony</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Micromax</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Karbonn</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem>Apple</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td>
         <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate = "DDL_Product" OnServerValidate="ddl_server" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Please Select the Product"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
```

Default1.aspx.cs

```
protected void ddl_server(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Value.selectedIndex <= 0)
     {
        e.IsValid = true;
     }
     else
     {
        e.IsValid = false;
     }
}
```

The above validation not validating.
I don't know how to use this control and validate the DropDownList. Please Correct the error.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to validate, the `DropDownList` having a selected value?

Comment: yes. If the index value cannot change from 0 or its value cannot change from "Select".

Comment: Then you don't need a `CustomeValidator`, what you need is a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use RequireValidator for this.

1) Add the value for the "Select" item, will be used to validate the initial value:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Product" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="128px">
       <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
       /*Rest of items*/
</asp:DropDownList>
```

2) Then use the RequireValidator like this, comparing the initial value from the DDL:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="0" 
    ID="rfvDDL_Product" Display="Dynamic" 
    ControlToValidate="DDL_Product"
    runat="server"  Text="*" 
    ErrorMessage="Please Select the Product"
    ForeColor="Red">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

EDIT:

For explanation, from MSDN:

[CustomValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)

> Use the CustomValidator control to provide a user-defined validation
>   function for an input control. The CustomValidator control is a
>   separate control from the input control it validates, which allows you
>   to control where the validation message is displayed.

[RequiredFieldValidator Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx)

> Use this control to make an input control a required field. The input
>   control fails validation if its value does not change from the
>   InitialValue property upon losing focus.

Comment: thanks alot.. Its working. May i know the reasong for why using RequiredFieldValidator here and where the Custom Validator are applicable to use.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the property `AutoPostBack="true"` in the `DropDownList`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDL_Product" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="128px"
                  AutoPostBack="true">
```

and also if it's only to verify if a value was selected, consider using a `RequiredFieldValidator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `ValidateEmptyText="true"` to your custom validator as follows to also validate if nothing is selected:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" Display="Dynamic" 
                     ControlToValidate = "DDL_Product" 
                     OnServerValidate="ddl_server" 
                     runat="server" ForeColor="Red" 
                     ErrorMessage="Please Select the Product"
                     ValidateEmptyText="true">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```